# Error in SQL syntax regarding insert function and POST functions

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry to be such a bother again, however it seems i am facing a bit of trouble with my coding.
For some reason i am presented with the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' '', 'No Subject', 0, 'Jul 8, 2013 09:33 PM', 0)' at line 1
```

Whenever i execute the following command:

```
        $date_posted=date("M j, Y h:i A", TIME());
$sent_to=$_POST["member_id"];
    $sent_by=$_SESSION["member_id"];
    $subject=addslashes($_POST["subject"]);
    if($subject==Null)
    {
        $subject="No Subject";
    }
    $subject=verify_data($subject);

    $message=addslashes($_POST["message"]);
    $message=verify_data($message);


                    $sql="insert into main";
            $sql.="(member_id";
            $sql.=", mail_to";
            $sql.=", mess_text";
            $sql.=", subject";
            $sql.=", deleted";
            $sql.=", date_posted";
            $sql.=", mess_read)";

            $sql.=" values($sent_by";
            $sql.=", $sent_to";
            $sql.=", '$message'";
            $sql.=", '$subject'";
            $sql.=", 0";
            $sql.=", '$date_posted'";
            $sql.=", 0)";
            $result=mysql_query($sql);
            print mysql_error();
if($result)
            {
                            print "<font color='red'>Message sent successfully.</font>";
            }
            else
            {
                            //print "<font color='red'>A system error has happened, be patient.</font>";
            }
```

If i'm correct, the problem should lie within the coding values or the POST functions themselves, the thing is, i've changed from _POST to HTTP_POST_VARS and it hasn't really been of much help.

Although i will say that the MYSQL values for mail are as follows:

```
member_id type int(11)
mail_to type int(11)
mess_text type blob
deleted type int(11)
subject type blob
date_posted type varchar(255)
mess_read type int(11)
```

Result when: echo $sql:

```
insert into mail(member_id, mail_to, mess_text, subject, deleted, date_posted, mess_read) values(2, , '', 'No Subject', 0, 'Jul 8, 2013 09:43 PM', 0)
```

If you're able to help me resolve this concern, then it's much appreciated.
This community has been of great support not just to beginners like myself, but for experts who sometimes require that little push of effort.

Comment: @VaibhavDesai - What do you mean?

Comment: Add `echo $sql;` to your script, and show us the output.

Comment: @VaibhavDesai - Done, i echoed the script. The results are shown in the modified post.

Comment: if your $sent_to or $sent_by becomes empty then it will fail

Comment: @DevZer0 - Ah, no wonder haha. I'll see what i can do. Although for sure i thought i had the problem solved :/

Comment: you cant leave 2nd column just empty. repace it with null or empty('') as per table schema

Comment: Looks like `$sent_to=$_POST["member_id"]` is empty

Comment: check for the value of $sent_to=$_POST["member_id"]; and $sent_by=$_SESSION["member_id"];

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data
This is the script i'm currently using on my site.
For sure, the post functions doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: Check to make sure your form input is `name="member_id"`, case sensitive, etc.

Comment: @Sean - for sure the value output are numerical, them come out as stated in the member_id.

Comment: but if `$_POST["member_id"]` is empty, the first place I would look is the form element to make sure it is valid. It is very common when working with JQuery that only the id is defined `<input id='member_id' >`, but not the name, which would lead to the post value being empty.

Comment: @Sean - There are two forms actually: <input id="project" />
<input type="hidden" id="member_id" />

Comment: And neither have a `name` attribute. Without the name attribute, you cannot access the value on post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form elements have to have a `name` in order to access them on form submit. So in order to use -

```
$sent_to=$_POST["member_id"];
```

You have to have a element that looks like this -

```
<input name="member_id" />
```

It is very common when using JQuery for examples to only include the id -

```
<input type="hidden" id="project-id" />  // from the autocomplete source code example
```

This works in javascript/JQuery, as you are working with the `id`, but in php you need to add the name -

```
<input type="hidden" id="member_id" name="member_id" />
```

Comment: There ya go, i accepted your answer. Works perfectly too, i just test it once again in test accounts.

Answer (score 0):

if your `$sent_to` or `$sent_by` becomes empty then it will fail. Based on your SQL string you posted it seems $sent_to is empty, either check to make sure this value exist or put single quotes around the value so you can pass an empty value to the database,

Comment: hm... oddly enough i modified the POST functions and i still can't seem to output what i need.

Comment: Well, since i am using an external JQuery script
(http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data) i just changed the "project-id" tag to "member_id" so Supposible it'll work.

Comment: your making the form post after the selection of row from auto complete?

Comment: @Blahwhore If you look at the source code in that jquery ui example, they are only setting the id attribute, not the name attribute, so that input is not accessible on form post - `<input type="hidden" id="project-id" />`. So if you only changed `project-id` to `member_id`, you also need to add `name="member_id"`

Comment: yeah, that's how i'm planning on doing it.

Answer (score 0):

> $sent_to= (isset( $_POST["member_id"]) && $_POST["member_id"] != '') ?
>   $_POST["member_id"] : '';

or

> $sent_to= (isset( $_POST["member_id"]) && $_POST["member_id"] != '') ?
>   $_POST["member_id"] : null; // if it accepts null

--edit---

> mail_to can accept int

so,

> $sent_to= (isset( $_POST["member_id"]) && $_POST["member_id"] != '') ?
>   $_POST["member_id"] : 0; //it can be zero or any default value you want to be

Comment: Not yet, although i'm starting to suspect that int(X) functions don't work with POST function.

Comment: what the default value you want to be for mail_to. you can set in db itself. or set it 0 or if can force a mail_to value to send to post.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here $sent_to is blank so there is a error

check for the $_POST["member_id"] value.
```

AND

```
       $sql="insert into main";
        $sql.="(member_id";
        $sql.=", mail_to";
        $sql.=", mess_text";
        $sql.=", subject";
        $sql.=", deleted";
        $sql.=", date_posted";
        $sql.=", mess_read)";

        $sql.=" values($sent_by";
        $sql.=", $sent_to";
        $sql.=", '$message'";
        $sql.=", '$subject'";
        $sql.=", 0";
        $sql.=", '$date_posted'";
        $sql.=", 0)";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);


    TO


    $sql="insert into main";
    $sql.="(member_id";
    $sql.=", mail_to";
    $sql.=", mess_text";
    $sql.=", subject";
    $sql.=", deleted";
    $sql.=", date_posted";
    $sql.=", mess_read)";

    $sql.=" values('$sent_by'";
    $sql.=", '$sent_to'";
    $sql.=", '$message'";
    $sql.=", '$subject'";
    $sql.=", 0";
    $sql.=", '$date_posted'";
    $sql.=", 0)";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: hm... the "message sent" notification shows up, but the post option doesn't seem to be working still.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php
    /*$db_host='localhost';
    $db_user='root';
    $db_pass='';
    $db_name='example';*/

    $dbc = mysql_connect("localhost","root","admin123") or die('Connection to database failed');
    mysql_select_db("example",$dbc);
    //$fname =$_POST['first_name'];
    //$lname =$_POST['last_name'];

    $sql="INSERT INTO table(first_name,last_name) VALUES('Prashant','Bhatta')";

    mysql_query($sql,$dbc) or die (mysql_error());

?>
```